# Can I substitute peppercorn marinade for peppercorn sauce mix in a recipe?

Tags: substitutions, crockpot

The recipe is for crockpot turkey, with turkey breast, merlot, onions, cranberry sauce and 1 oz knorr peppercorn sauce mix. I used 1oz peppercorn marinade mix. Will it ruin it?

Comment: Since you already used it, you're in the best position of all to judge: Was it?

Comment: no I simply mixed it with cranberry sauce and Merlot for turkey crockpot recipe tomorrow.... I haven't done it yet

Comment: Define "OK". Also, what is "peppercorn sauce mix", and what is "peppercorn marinade"? These are not standard cooking terms.

Comment: I think you may have a legitimate question, but you need to give us more information. I guess what I think you're asking is "What will happen to my dish, given that I am using X instead of Y." You'll need to tell us what is in both X and Y as well as more information about what you're making and how.

Comment: Sandra lee crockpot recipe

Comment: Sandra lee crockpot recipe
Turkey breast, merlot, onions, cranberry sauce and knorr peppercorn sauce mix 1oz
I used 1oz peppercorn marinade mix
Will it ruin it? I'm cooking it now

Comment: That still doesn't really help us... what's in the marinade, what's in the mix? At very least can you send us a link to the products?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be the exact same thing as the original recipe; you've essentially seasoned it differently. So I'd expect it won't be better or worse just different, but depending on your tastes it might well be better or worse. I can imagine it ending up under-salted since the marinade mix might be less salty than the sauce mix.